# mysql service in wamp 3.0.6 32bit not starting

Tags: mysql, wamp

I am getting `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)` after installing wamp. Also wampmysqld and wampmysqld64 services status is stopped, when started again comes to stopped status.

When checking mysql logs file it shows:

```
2017-04-18T04:12:28.912737Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist 
2017-04-18T04:12:28.912737Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I have spent 2 days on it and tried everything.Please someone give any solution.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to run WAMPServer 32bit and WAMPServer 64bit both at the same time? If so dont.

Comment: Sounds like the install may have had a problem. You did install under an Admin account as suggested in the Install I hope.

Comment: Thanks Riggs.it works. i had not installed it under Admin account.its so delightful to see green wamp icon.

Comment: Also note there is a simple addon to get you to WAMPServer 3.0.8, that only effects the WAMPServer code and not Apache/MySQL//PHP. But this update allows you to download MariaDB as well as MYSQL if you so desire.

Comment: thats cool ! would definitely use that.